# Как убрать лайки и дизлайки со всех видео в ютубе про своего аккаунта

Tags: python, json, requests, bs4, youtube

Хочу стереть все лайки и дизлайки, которые были в YouTube из своего аккаунта. Что надо для этого сделать. Хочу это через requests и bs4 и питон

Answer (score 0):

Это довольно непростая задача, особенно с таким набором инструментов. Судя по вашему вопросу вы ещё не понимаете насколько это сложно. Но если все же решите продолжить, вот краткий набросок алгоритма.

Посмотрите с помощью инструментов разработчика на структуру страницы с понравившимися видео. Парсите от туда ссылки на эти видео. Затем заходите на эти видео, и отправляете запросы, генерируемые при нажатии на лайк. Посмотреть какой запрос отправляет сервер можно  во вкладке Network. Изучите структуру страцицы с видео и спарсите также данные, необходимые для запроса